# jQuery UI Modal Destroy Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui

Form is submitted multiple times even when i destroy the modal and then reopen again.

Although in the modal contain only one form:

please help how to prevent / submit only one form on the dialog!

HTML:

```
<a href="modal.php" class="mymodal" title="Submit Form">Open Modal</a>
```

Modal.php file

```
<form id="myform" role="form">

<div><label>Username:</label> <input type="text" name="uname"></div>
<div><label>Message:</label> <input type="text" name="message"></div>
<div><input type="submit" name="submit"></div>

</form>
```

JS:

```
$('body').on('click','.mymodal', function(e){

  var $this = $(this); 
  var output = $('<div id="uimodal-output" title="'+$this.prop('title')+'"></div>');
  $('body').append(output);

  output.load( $this.attr('href'), null, function() {
    output.dialog({
      modal: true,
      width:'auto',
      position: 'center',
      close: function(event, ui) {
         $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
         $('#uimodal-output').dialog('destroy').remove(); // destroy all 
      }
    });
  })

});

$('body').on('click','#myform', function(e){

   $.ajax({
   });

   return false;
});
```

Comment: Second click method (for the form, the one containing the ajax) is what?

Answer (score 1):

The issue I believe is because you're clicking an anchor with  a valid `href` for opening the model. So it'll follow the `href`.

prevent the default action of `<a>` using `event.preventDefault()` :

```
$('body').on('click','.mymodal', function(e){

  e.preventDefault(); // add this

  var $this = $(this); 
  var output = $('<div id="uimodal-output" title="'+$this.prop('title')+'"></div>');
  $('body').append(output);
  output.load( $this.attr('href'), null, function() {
    output.dialog({
      modal: true,
      width:'auto',
      position: 'center',
      close: function(event, ui) {
       $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
       $('#uimodal-output').dialog('destroy').remove(); // destroy all 
     }
    });
  })
});
```